# How to use a 2.4 GHz chip antenna for ESP32 design

Tags: pcb, rf, antenna, diy

I am designing a circuit board that will use a 2.4 GHz SMD chip antenna from Molex. I am a n00b/amateur at PCB design so forgive my ignorance - does it work nearly the same as how a PCB antenna works?

I have spent quite a while trying to dig through the datasheet for the Molex SMD 47948 chip antenna (details [here](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Molex/47948-0001?qs=VBGyBZiQP4FMDCbO62oZvg%3D%3D)) but I cannot make much sense of how to use it.

Is this the correct way to use it? I've used PCB trace antennas in the past and they work perfectly. However, with PCB antennas, usually they have two connections, signal and GND as two inputs going into the antenna trace. But with this chip antenna it only seems to have a single input? Do I also need to connect the trace going into the antenna to ground as well?

[image: Schematic]

[image: PCB Design]

Comment: No there's no ground connection on those antennas. But you should probably try to follow Molex's design recommendations, both for the footprint as well as overall layout, more closely to get decent performance. The recommended footprint is [here](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/ps/PS-47948-001-001.pdf), and additional application info [here](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/as/AS-47948-001-001.pdf). You'll notice that they seem to always position the part on a corner of the board.

Comment: Running the antenna trace thru those vias is probably not a good idea either, and it doesn't look like you've paid any attention to trace characteristic impedance. You probably also need a *lot* more ground-plane stitching vias around the matching network too,

Answer (score 2):

I am 2 years late,

The product specification document
http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/ps/PS-47948-001-001.pdf

has a layout guide, Pleas follow it.

[image]